# awk doesn't work in hadoop's mapper

Tags: awk, hadoop-streaming

This is my hadoop job:

```
hadoop streaming \
-D mapred.map.tasks=1\
-D mapred.reduce.tasks=1\
-mapper "awk '{if(\$0<3)print}'" \  # doesn't work
-reducer "cat" \
-input "/user/***/input/" \
-output "/user/***/out/"
```

this job always fails, with an error saying:

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `export TMPDIR='..../work/tmp'; /bin/awk { if ($0 < 3) print } '
```

But if I change the `-mapper` into this:
-mapper "awk '{print}'" 
it works without any error. What's the problem with the `if(..)` ?

UPDATE:

Thank @paxdiablo for your detailed answer.

what I really want to do is filter out some data whose 1st column is greater than `x`, before piping the input data to my custom `bin`. So the `-mapper` actually looks like this:

```
-mapper "awk -v x=$x{if($0<x)print} | ./bin"
```

Is there any other way to achieve that?

Comment: By the way, Alcott, `$0` is the entire input line. If you want just the first field, that's `$1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem's not with the `if` per se, it's to do with the fact that the quotes have been stripped from your `awk` command.

You'll realise this when you look at the error output:

```
sh: -c: line 0: `export TMPDIR='..../work/tmp'; /bin/awk { if ($0 < 3) print } '
```

and when you try to execute that quote-stripped command directly:

```
pax> echo hello | awk {if($0<3)print}
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

pax> echo hello | awk {print}
hello
```

The reason the `{print}` one works is because it doesn't contain the shell-special `(` character.

One thing you might want to try is to escape the special characters to ensure the shell doesn't try to interpret them:

```
{if\(\$0\<3\)print}
```

It may take some effort to get the correctly escaped string but you can look at the error output to see what is generated. I've had to escape the `()` since they're shell sub-shell creation commands, the `$` to prevent variable expansion, and the `<` to prevent input redirection.

---

Also keep in mind that there may be other ways to filter depending on you needs, ways that can avoid shell-special characters. If you specify what your needs are, we can possibly help further.

For example, you could create an shell script (eg, `pax.sh`) to do the actual `awk` work for you:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -v x=$1 'if($1<x){print}'
```

then use that shell script in the mapper without any special shell characters:

```
hadoop streaming \
  -D mapred.map.tasks=1 -D mapred.reduce.tasks=1 \
  -mapper "pax.sh 3" -reducer "cat" \
  -input "/user/***/input/" -output "/user/***/out/"
```

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my post adding my real purpose for doing that.

Comment: @Alcott, I've added one possibility which may make it workable. See the updated answer.